# Apply application-wide custom font on Android

Tags: android, android-theme, custom-font

I am trying to use Android Oreo [custom font](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) feature in my application.
It works fine if I set the font manually on each `TextView`, but when trying to set it globally in my application theme, it has some issues.

My theme looks like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other attributes -->
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_font</item>
</style>
```

The font is correctly applied in the `BottomNavigationView` and the `Button`s, but not in the `Toolbar` or `TextView` with a `style` (like `Body1`).

Is there a simple way to set a custom font on the whole application? Do I have to override each style to add the `fontFamilly` attribute?

**Update:** I was using the `style` attribute to set my text appearance, instead of `android:textAppearance`. Using the later fixed most of my issues with custom font. Now, only the `Toolbar` is still using the default font.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to apply font application wide, but activity wide is possible.

Checkout this [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm already using Calligraphy, and I was hoping to remove this dependency with Android's native support for custom font. I will keep Calligraphy if it is not possible (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect implementation.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-library-recommendations

Library:

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: if you find my answer useful then fell free to upvote it. You can also mark it as the solution to your question by clicking the Green Tick Mark.

Comment: I'm already using Calligraphy, and I was hoping to remove this dependency with Android's native support for custom font. I will keep Calligraphy if it is not possible (yet).